# how to remove OnSeekBarChangeListener once set in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, listener, seekbar

I've searched around and tried some of the suggestions but still no success.

I have a listview that contain seekbars that are used to set parameters in the code. I would like to trigger the seekbar listener based on a toggle button so that the user does not accidentally move the seekbars while scrolling the list.

my problem is that once the toggle is turned off, the seekbar listener is still active. I've tried passing null to the setOnSeekBarChangeListener, but it does not work.

thanks for your help. I'm a newbie to Android and handling the user intput chain of events is still confusing to me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
mySeekBar.setEnabled(false);
```

EDIT:

Try setting the focus to false like this..

```
  mySeekBar.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just tried that as well and it does not seem to work also. I wonder if it has to do with setting the listener in the listadapter.

Comment: i just tried that as well and it also does not work, but I'm thinking Flexo's answer might be working but I am confused with that is going on in the list adapter. please see my reply to him.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
myView.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null);
```

Comment: At least, this work when i want to remover a listener from a view

Comment: I tried that and it does not seem to work for me. I am setting the listener in the getView method of the listadapter based on the state of the toggle button. But passing null does not seem to work, and am not sure what to do other than account for the toggle state in the listener callback, but it seems inefficient to do that.

Comment: So I think this the right solution, but I am getting confused about what is going on in the list adapter. Basically if I move scroll the seekbar out of view and then back again, the listener is canceled. So I tried to invalidate the view after the toggle changes, and it does not work. I have to literally scroll the seekbar out of view and back again. so this issue might have to do with the refresh of the list.

Comment: I gave up and implemented the toggle button state in the seekbar listener. its working fine, so i'm moving on. but for sure the issue had to do with redrawing of the list in order to apply the null listener.